# Firebase UI tableview binding doesn't reload on back nav

Tags: ios, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am using FirebaseUI to bind my firebase database references to a tableView within my app. When I push another ViewController on top, make changes to my data, and then pop that ViewController, the data within the TableView does not reload.

```
let childRef = self.ref.child("reports").queryOrdered(byChild: "project").queryEqual(toValue: self.projectKey)

    self.dataSource = self.tableView.bind(to: childRef as! FIRDatabaseQuery) { projectsTableView, indexPath, snap in
        let cell = projectsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        // Populate cell as you see fit, like as below
        let value = snap.value as? NSDictionary
        let type = value?["punchListType"] as? String ?? ""
        let date = value?["siteVisitDate"] as? String ?? ""
        let reportText = "\(type) - \(date)"
        self.reportKeys.append(snap.key)
        cell.textLabel?.text = reportText

        print(value)

        var report = Report()
        report.preparedBy = value?["preparedBy"] as? String ?? ""
        report.punchListType = value?["punchListType"] as? String ?? ""
        report.siteVisitDate = value?["siteVisitDate"] as? String ?? ""
        let notes = value?["notes"] as? NSArray
        for note in notes! {
            report.notes.append(note as! String)
        }
        report.key = snap.key

        self.reports.append(report)

        return cell
    }
```

This is an example of a binding I have in my class. If I were to go to another ViewController to edit the Report details, and then navigate back to the ReportsTableView, the data won't reload.

I have attempted to call `self.tableView.reloadData()`, but that did nothing. The only way I can get it to reload the data is if I pop ReportsTableView and and then repush it onto the View stack.

Any suggestions for how I can get the tableView to update the data?

Comment: Where is this code run viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear?

Comment: I added it to both and neither worked. Currently, it is being called in viewWillAppear